# Graded modules and the I-adic topology.

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Matsumura *Commutative Ring Theory*, Theorem 16.3, p.126:

> Let $A$ be a Noetherian ring, $M \not= 0$ an $A$-module and $a_1, ..., a_n \in A$; set $I = (a_1, ... , a_n)A$. Under the condition
>
> (*) each of $M, M/a_1M, \dots, M/(a_1,..., a_{n-1})M$ is $I$-adically separated
>
> if $a_1, ... , a_n$ is $M$-quasi-regular it is an $M$-sequence.

The author mentions that condition (*) holds automatically in this particular case:

> $A$ is an $\Bbb{N}$-graded ring, $M$ an $\Bbb{N}$-graded module, and each $a_i$ homogeneous of positive degree.

I have trouble seeing why this is true. Suppose that $A = \oplus_{i \in{\Bbb{N}}} A_i$ and $M = \oplus_{i \in{\Bbb{N}}} M_i$. Then we must show that $M$ is $I$-adically separated, which is equivalent to showing that $M \cap IM \cap I^2M \cap ... = 0$, right? I'm not exactly sure what to do and would appreciate any hints.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If take a homogeneous element $x$ in the intersection, then its degree should be arbitrary large since $x\in I^mM$ for all $m\ge 1$, so $x=0$.

Comment: Thanks, but there are two things that still confuse me. 1) What if $M = \oplus M_i$ where $M_j = M_{j+1}$ for all sufficiently large $j$? Then there might be nonzero elements of arbitrary degree, right? We would have $M_0 \supseteq M_1 \supseteq ... \supseteq M_j = M_{j+1} = ...$.

Comment: It seems to me that you ignore $I^m$ whose homogeneous elements have degree $\ge m$. ($I$ and $M$ are both homogeneous.)

Comment: Thanks, I guess I understand what you mean. However, can we assume that $M = \oplus M_i$ with $M_i = I^iM$? The assumption does not say that, does it? It only says $M$ is an arbitrary graded module where $M_i$ can be anything. Am I misunderstanding it? Or does the author assume that $M_i = I^iM$ without saying it explicitly?

Comment: No, it's not supposed that $M_i=I^iM$ and you don't need it.

Comment: I got to this post with the same question and figured it out thanks to the answer. And from what I have been thinking, it is enough to consider only homogeneous elements in the intersection because each submodule in the intersection is a homogeneous submodule of $M$(an equivalent definition is that all the homogeneous components of an element of the submodule are in it.)